# Plotly How to create a line animation with column name in x axis and column data in y axis?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a data frame as shown below.

```
Device_ID Die_Version   Temp(deg)   sup(V)  freq    sensitivity THD_94  THD_100 THD_105 THD_110 THD_112 THD_114 THD_115 THD_116 THD_118 THD_120
TTM_041    0x16          -40             1.8    0.8 -25.041          0.009  0.01    0.071   0.206   0.143   0.099   0.1 0.296   4.243   11.888
TTM_041    0x16          -40             1.8    2.4 -25.041          0.009  0.01    0.075   0.206   0.143   0.1 0.101   0.245   4.495   11.728
TTM_041    0x16          -40             1.98   0.8 -25.04       0.009  0.01    0.076   0.207   0.143   0.1 0.102   0.313   4.484   11.844
```

I need to plot the graph in such a way that column names (THD_94    THD_100 THD_105 THD_110 THD_112 THD_114 THD_115 THD_116 THD_118 THD_120) needs to come in the X axis and its values need to come in the Y axis.

I tried with below code, but it is not working as expected.

```
fig = px.line(df_MM_SPEC, x=px.Constant('col'), y=['THD_94', 'THD_100'], animation_frame='Device_ID')
# fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Comment: could you add your data in form of a dictionary where the keys are the column names the values of the dict  are a list? Would be easy to reproduce your data

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this. If you don't mind, could you please show me how to do that.

Comment: sure. First let you know it does not to be in the exact format I asked, but anything that is easy to read from with pandas, and at the same time is easy to give in the form of text. I think dictionaries are good for this. if you have a data_frame you can do `df.to_dict()` and give the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reshaped_df = df[[col for col in df.columns if 'THD' in col]].T.stack().reset_index()
```

gives us some reshaped data that looks like this:

```
    level_0  level_1       0
0    THD_94        0   0.009
1    THD_94        1   0.009
2    THD_94        2   0.009
3   THD_100        0   0.010
4   THD_100        1   0.010
5   THD_100        2   0.010
6   THD_105        0   0.071
7   THD_105        1   0.075
8   THD_105        2   0.076
9   THD_110        0   0.206
10  THD_110        1   0.206
11  THD_110        2   0.207
12  THD_112        0   0.143
13  THD_112        1   0.143
14  THD_112        2   0.143
15  THD_114        0   0.099
16  THD_114        1   0.100
17  THD_114        2   0.100
18  THD_115        0   0.100
19  THD_115        1   0.101
20  THD_115        2   0.102
21  THD_116        0   0.296
22  THD_116        1   0.245
23  THD_116        2   0.313
24  THD_118        0   4.243
25  THD_118        1   4.495
26  THD_118        2   4.484
27  THD_120        0  11.888
28  THD_120        1  11.728
29  THD_120        2  11.844
```

It might be wise to rename your columns to something more logical, but I'll leave that to the reader.  With the reshaped data, it's pretty trivial to animate:

```
px.line(reshaped_df, x='level_0', y=0, animation_frame='level_1')
```

[image]